# JavaScript error: 'angular' is undefined - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, runtime-error, unhandled-exception

Should be a basic solution but for the life of me I don't see what is wrong.

I am attempting to run an Angular JS application and I am getting a runtime error:

> JavaScript runtime error: 'angular' is undefined

Here is my code below.

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
  app.controller('MyAppController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Hello, World!";
  });
}());
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> Angular JS App </h1>

  <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyAppController">
    <label> {{message}} </label>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Move ng-app from html to body: <body ng-app="MyApp">

Comment: It is not undefined it is raising errors

Comment: you should have only one **ng-app** and in put it in body tag itself is advisable.

Comment: Thank you for the input - I have addressed the ng-app problem by moving it to the body tag. However, I am still getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

You placed your *ngApp* directive twice in your view template.

https://plnkr.co/edit/cSTHyVqMHFVw8ht9mkIr

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <h1> Angular JS App </h1>

  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <label> {{message}} </label>
  </div>


</body>
```

Declaring once will solve your issue.